# How to run function with for-loop in console?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

A website only shows some links after clicking on some buttons, but you can trigger these buttons using the js-console of Chrome.

Command:

```
expandPack('S151')
```

Basically, the only thing that changes to get the other links is the number (in the example 151)

So how can I use a for loop to get all links with the ids 1-300?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard loop...

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
    expandPack("S" + i);
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, I have to use a plus, to add the i into the Command, thank you ^^ (I tried it with & before...)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to do this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 300; i += 1) {
    expandPack('S' + i);
}
```